# scribd_fu takes very long (~20 minutes for 1 MB PDF)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, scribd

Do you have an idea why sribd_fu takes very long to convert PDF files?
I tested it with a 1 MB PDF-file. Converting took around 20 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scribd_fu doesn't do the processing, it just uploads to Scribd and they process the file. I've never experienced waits that long -- have you tried again today? Perhaps their service was having issues?